# paypal smart payment button display issue

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout

I have created PayPal Smart Payment Buttons in my application. By default it is showing two buttons first button for PayPal login window, and second button for Debit or Credit Card window.

On clicking the second button the first button is not displaying. I can see the both buttons in chrome developer console. `margin-top:59px` property is added by the script.

Here you can try PayPal's [interactive code demo](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/checkout).

How do I get rid of it? Is there a setting somewhere to show both when button click?

Comment: This caused me so many issues having a fixed design style

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want to get rid of it? The second button is for entering a debit or credit cads and paying as a guest. Typically this is a much-desired feature, not something people want to get rid of.

When clicked, the top button is being moved out of the way to make good use of screen real estate, since the debit or credit card button does *not* open a window. It expands the iframe *inside* the container  (which is actually rather amazing to those of us who've been in the payment industry for a long time.)

If you truly want to get rid of card processing, you can. The Smart Payment Buttons documentation has options for disabling funding sources. Basically add `&disable-funding=card` after your ClientID when invoking the SDK js:

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&disable-funding=card"></script>
```